# Build Mapbox pod iOS with Kotlin/Native Multiplatform

Tags: ios, cocoapods, mapbox, kotlin-native, mapbox-ios

I'm trying to add Mapbox to Kotlin/Native project, where I use cocoapods:
*(already set up for Android - works fine)*

```
    //plugin 
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    
    //pod
    cocoapods {
        // Configure fields required by CocoaPods.
        summary = "Some description for a Kotlin/Native module"
        homepage = "Link to a Kotlin/Native module homepage"

        pod("Mapbox-iOS-SDK", "~> 6.0.0")
    }
```

**Pod run through the Kotlin/Native doesn't read  `.netrc` file with credentials:**

```
machine api.mapbox.com 
login name
password pass
```

In pod file I added my library:

```
pod 'SharedCode', :path => 'kotlin_native/SharedCode'
```

The error I see when I run `pod install`:

```
[!] Error installing Mapbox-iOS-SDK
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/vk/rb1bs6ld7wd19cmg6srw9s080000gn/T/d20200728-92875-1y3089q/file.zip https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/mobile-maps/releases/ios/packages/6.0.0/mapbox-ios-sdk-dynamic.zip --create-dirs --netrc-optional --retry 2

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (22) The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized
```

If I add pod to iOS project directly, it works ok:

```
#pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 5.0.0'
```

***How can I make it read credentials file? Is it possible?***

Also, I tried to use `podspec` and put `access_token` in the URL but it doesn't work (*with or without token*), not sure if it is not supported or made syntax mistake?

```
ArgumentError - Illformed requirement `":podspec => https://github.com/mapbox/pod-specs/blob/master/Mapbox-iOS-SDK/5.2.0/Mapbox-iOS-SDK.podspec"`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this feature is not supported at the moment. Kotlin version 1.4-RC should introduce a possible workaround. One can try calling `curl` manually and then import local CocoaPods dependency as it is done in [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlin-with-cocoapods-sample/blob/master/kotlin-library/build.gradle.kts#L31) sample.

---

I would also recommend you to file an issue here(https://kotl.in/issue). Supporting credentials is important, and should be put on the Kotlin team's list.

Answer (score 0):

The login has to be "mapbox" : mapbox documentation : https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/overview/#configure-credentials

```
machine api.mapbox.com
login mapbox
password <INSERT API TOKEN>
```

Bonus tips :
You can add credential before pod install / pod update process and remove it after with this macos script for example:

```
echo "Generate credential for mapbox"
echo "machine api.mapbox.com" > ~/.netrc
echo "login mapbox" >> ~/.netrc
echo "password <INSERT API TOKEN>" >> ~/.netrc
```

To delete this entry later :

```
sed -i '' -e '/^machine api.mapbox.com$/{N;N;d;}' ~/.netrc
```